# Converting cos(x-30) to two terms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have a worked example in front of me for a particle kinetics and kinematics question. In the working it has a an equation:

$$0.6=\frac{V_0\sin(60)+V^`cos(x-30)}{10cos(30)}$$

And on the next line they have:

$$5.196=0.866V_0 + 0.866V^`cos(x)+0.5V`sin(x)$$

I can't seem to figure out how they got $$0.866V^`cos(x)+0.5V`sin(x)$$ from $$V^`cos(x-30)$$

Am I missing some information from somewhere else in the question, or is there some sort of logic to this transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\cos(A+B)=\cos A \cos B -\sin A \sin B$

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities

Comment: Holy hell... Back to school for me. I tried searching that term over and over, put it in Wolfram, calculator everything... Thank you